# Need javascript to calculate grade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following grade displayed dynamically

I want to calculate total grade after the data is loaded.

```
    <div class="grade" id="grade-1">70</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-2">90</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-3">80</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-4">60</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-5">90</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-6">80</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-7">80</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-8">60</div>
    <div class="grade" id="grade-9">90</div>
    .............
    .............
```

using javascript I want to calculate this total, number of grades are dynamic.
help me out.

Comment: have you tried anything, if so show some JS

Comment: that being the total of the numeric values found inside the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = 0;

$("div.grade").each(function() { total += parseFloat($(this).html()); } );
```

Comment: use `.text()`, not `.html()`.

Comment: in the each loop i get only one element so the html() will do the work

Comment: That's not the point - you only want the text content of the node, and no tags, so use `.text`.

Comment: but in the structure he mentioned there is no nested elements.if there were text() would have combined their text as mentioned in jquery doc.

Comment: No, if you used it inside the `.each` it'll only get one div's contents as a time.  Anyhow, the real point is that if you only want text content, always use `.text()`.  Get in to the habit of only using `.html()` if you're intentionally reading or writing element nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each()` to loop through all elements :

```
 var gradesum=0;
 $('.grade').each(function(){gradesum+= parseInt($(this).text());});
 alert(gradesum);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4vR4/3/)**

Comment: I want total of all grades.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var total_grade = 0;

$('.grade').each(function() {
    total_grade += parseInt($(this).text());
});

console.log(total_grade);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascripts [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function as an alternative as well:

```
var grades = document.querySelectorAll(".grade"),
    grades = Array.prototype.slice.call(grades);

var total = grades.reduce(function(previous, current, index, array){
    return parseInt(previous, 10) + parseInt(array[index].textContent, 10);
}, 0);
```

A few things of note here:

- Since `querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist, we must use `Array.prototype.slice` to turn our results into a proper array.
- Don't forget the radix on `parseInt`.
- I've broken this all out for clarity and readability.
- This is a pure javascript example, but is easily adaptable using jQuery.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BTvsL/

As pointed out in the comments, you could do something similar by combining `map` and `reduce`:

```
var grades = document.querySelectorAll(".grade");
    grades = Array.prototype.slice.call(grades);

var total = grades.map(function(el){
    return parseInt(el.textContent, 10);
}).reduce(function(previous, current){
    return previous + current;
}, 0);
```

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/BTvsL/1/

*Note: If you need to test between `.innerHTML` vs `.innerText` given your browser requirements, you can do so by testing for each and defaulting to 0 like so:*

```
var text = el.textContent || el.innerText || 0;
```

Comment: IMHO, better to use `.map` to handle the conversion from node to value and then use `.reduce`.  Oh, and `.innerText` isn't W3C standard.

Comment: @Alnitak - updated for checking textContent or innerText

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but I suspect it'll fail on browsers that don't support `.innerText` if the grade is zero - the left hand branch of the `||` will fail, and then the right hand side will return `undefined`, causing the sum to become `NaN`.

Comment: @Alnitak - That's a good point. I've updated the above to just use textContent.

Comment: You could also use `.textContent || .innerText || 0`

Comment: Completely agree, just didn't figure it was worth cluttering the above for such a simple example after thinking about it. I'll add a note about it though for clarity. Thanks for looking out =)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jX4h2/)**

you can select the all element which is having .grade class .and sum the text

```
var total=0;
    $(".grade").each(function(){

       total+= +$(this).text();

    });
    alert(total);
```

Comment: see the  OP scenario then post the question

Comment: You are converting the string into a number by using `+`, what if the design changes to display the value as `10 %`..?

Comment: use parseInt("10%") to get only integer number

Answer (score 0):

For browsers compatible with ES5 and the latest W3C specifications, you can get the sum all in one go:

```
var sum = $('div.grade').map(function() {
    return +this.textContent || 0;  // || 0 to cope with any NaNs
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b }, 0);
```

i.e. get the elements, and the numeric value of their text content (compatible with IE9+), turn that into a native array and then use the ES5 standard function `Array.prototype.reduce` to calculate the sum of those values.

Comment: this will iterate twice.. one for making the array and the other one for calculating the sum.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  It's unlikely to make any significant difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do is to use jQuery `.map()` and javascript `.reduce()`

```
var total = $('.grade').map(function(){
        return $(this).text()*1; // to make sure this is a number 
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
alert(total);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxdY5/)